# Vimscript: how write regex in if statement

Tags: regex, if-statement, vim

I can search a regex with no problem, e.g.
`/["']`
but in an if statement it fails, e.g.

```
:let c = "w"
:if c !~ ["']
:echo "OK"
:endif
```

producing these error messages

> E114: Missing quote: "']
>   E15: Invalid expression: c !~ ["']

I've tried it umpteen different ways, bristling with backslashes, single and double quotes and 'very magic', but all I get is variation in the error messages.  How should I write this 'if' statement?

Comment: so I'm guessing just escaping the quotes ``[\"\']`` didn't work?

Comment: If its Perlish, you need delimiters `if c !~ /["']/`

Comment: Where in Perl `!~` is a regex operator (as is `=~`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the regex as string, try

```
:if c!~"[\"']"
```

Comment: That \ on the internal " makes all the difference. Thank you.

Comment: @Kent what if I would like to do a numerical comparison, say `if "^ *[0-9]\.[0-9]\{4}" < 5` i.e. the first number of each line should be less than 5?

Comment: @AlexanderCska regex is not the best way to do arithmetic calculations. You probably want to consider another way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I've personally had some problems with searching for `[` and an opposing `]` with Vim. Often times you can search either one independently with no problems, but when you combine both together, they need to be escaped.

So, try this: `\["'\]` and see if that works.

Comment: That produces  E15: Invalid expression: \\["'\\]
E15: Invalid expression: c !~ \\["'\\]